# error while doing sudo apt-get -f install

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am doing the `sudo apt-get -f install` and I am getting the following error. I have another ongoing discussion in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776678/too-many-errors-while-executing-dpkg-configure-a?noredirect=1#comment1161077_776678). The error I am getting after running `apt-get -f install` is given below :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc6 libc6:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6 libc6:i386
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
733 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,816 kB of archives.
After this operation, 338 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 320605 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.21-0ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libc6:i386 (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...

LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains the traditional /lib directory,
but not the multiarch directory /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.
It is not safe to upgrade the C library in this situation;
please remove the /lib/directory from LD_LIBRARY_PATH and
try again.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.21-0ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.21-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libc6:amd64 (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...

LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains the traditional /lib directory,
but not the multiarch directory /lib/i386-linux-gnu.
It is not safe to upgrade the C library in this situation;
please remove the /lib/directory from LD_LIBRARY_PATH and
try again.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.21-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.21-0ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.21-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
duttasankha@sankha-PC:~$ sudo apt-get update -fmy
E: Command line option 'f' [from -fmy] is not known.
duttasankha@sankha-PC:~$ sudo apt-get update -f
E: Command line option 'f' [from -f] is not known.
```

I also still have the gcc error which is not solved yet and still showing `#error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 4.9 are not supported!`. I am trying to google and solve but I am very much unaware about ubuntu or linux for that matter and I need your help. I am in real time bound situation right now and a help would be really really appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try executing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/i386-linux-gnu`

And then execute the command you were trying to use again.
    

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/1354124

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ran `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/i386-linux-gnu` and then did `sudo apt-get -f install` and got [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16661784/). The problem still persists.

Answer (score 3):

maybe this too late for answer this question but others might still looking for answer

Just type the code

```
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

then

```
apt full-upgrade
```

Hope it will work. 
Thank you